# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'sign_up' not found. 'sign_up' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

Django version 1.11.5,

views.py

```
class SignupPage(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserSignupForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

website/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView,LogoutView
from . import views

app_name = 'website'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='signin_2_w.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^signup/', views.SignupPage.as_view(), name='sign_up'),
```

forms.py

```
class UserSignupForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username','email','password1','password2')


        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = "Display Name"
        self.fields['email'].label = "Email Address"
        self.fields['password1'].label = "Password"
        self.fields['password2'].label = "Confirm Password"
```

proj/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomePage.as_view(),name='home'),
    url(r'^website/',include('website.urls',namespace='website')),
    url(r'^website/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^website/',views.StreamyePage.as_view(),name='streamye'),
    url(r'^thanks/$',views.ThanksPage.as_view(),name='thanks'),
    url(r'^congrats/$',views.CongratsPage.as_view(),name='congrats'),
    url(r'^aboutus/$',views.AboutusPage.as_view(),name='about_us'),
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
            {% else %}
             <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
             <li><a href="{% url 'sign_up' %}">Signup</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
```

In the above code, the signup page is throwing me a error -- "django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'sign_up' not found. 'sign_up' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Please someone help me out where im wrong!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: might need to be `website:sign_up`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to fix the links in the template to target the `website` urls :

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'website:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
         <li><a href="{% url 'website:login' %}">Login</a></li>
         <li><a href="{% url 'website:sign_up' %}">Signup</a></li>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? The `website` namespace apply to `django.contrib.auth.urls` too?

Comment: Isn't this the result of app-urls using `app_name = 'website'`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was that the session cookie was corrupted due to code changes.

I solved it by opening my app url in the incognitio mode(which will create fresh session cookie),

Then try non-incognitio normal url login.

Comment: Is this for a different problem? I'm not sure that a session cookie should break url processing in a template...

Comment: I was using cookie in different conditions, thus was getting error due to invalid cookie value

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django rest framework, this may help.

When you have router as,

```
router.register("path", SomeViewSet, basename="some-name")
```

Call the reverse as,

```
reverse("some-name-list")
```