# Reverse {% url %}: Reverse for '"' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I've been stuck on this for a while, can't seem to fix the error. I do not use `reverse()` anywhere in the view.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^book/", include("bookings.urls")),
]
```

**bookings.urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'bookings'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^charge/$', views.charge, name='charge'),
    url(r'^booking/$', views.booking, name='booking'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def booking(request):
     # some code
     render(request, 'bookings/template.html', {'listing': listing,})
def charge(request):
    # some code
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'bookings:charge' %}" method="post">
```

I tried all different alterations and namespaces, e.g. trying to use just `charge`, different namespaces in urls.py etc.

When I render the `book/booking/`, I get the following error:

> Reverse for 'charge' not found. 'charge' is not a valid view function
>   or pattern name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795690/django-urls-exceptions-noreversematch-reverse-for-sign-up-not-found-sign-up?rq=1

Comment: This is already what I have and it doesn't work. `bookings:charge` where  one the the app namespace and 2nd is the view name.

Comment: Which version of django you are using?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM 1.11.3

Comment: Even with update to 2.0, same error.

Comment: did you include app in settings.py ?

Comment: @VipinMohan yes, I'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: Can you post your full bookings.urls code, including imports

Comment: And full html as well,. My initial assessment is either a forgotten import, or a wrong url, in template, or even base template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use URL tag on that way, you need a `namespace` in your urls.py.

```
url(r"^book/", include("bookings.urls", namespace="bookings")),
```

Then you can have `{% url 'bookings:charge' %}` in your template.

Comment: Turns out I had multiple form instances in the template, which caused the error. One with `bookings:charge` and `charge` for another. Removing one fixed the issue. I will just mark this correct