# Problems with getting content from mySQL server to webpage via django

Tags: python, mysql, django

This is the first time I am using mySQL and django, and I have some problems with getting my content from the server and show it on my webpage.
Here is my codes:
This is the index.html

```
{% extends 'test/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<hr>
<br>
<h1 class="container center-align">{{title}}</h1>
<br>
<h3 class="center-align blue lighten-3">Webpages</h3>
<ul class="collection">
    {% for homes in homes %}
      <li class="collection-item"><a href="test/details.html">{{homes.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

The views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Home

def index(request):

    homes = Home.objects.all()[:10]

    context = {
        'title': 'All Home',
        'homes': homes
    }

    return render(request, 'test/index.html', context)


def details(request, id):
    home = Home.objects.get(id=id)

    context = {
    'Home': home
    }

    return render(request, 'test/details.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'details/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.details, name='details')
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Home(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Home"
```

details.html

```
{% extends 'test/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<hr>
<br>
<h1 class="container center-align">{{home.title}}</h1>
<br>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
        {{home.body}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
        {{created_at}}
    </div>
</div>
<a href="/test" class="btn">Go Back</a>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that when i click on the links on my webpage, the details.html file with the text form the server don't show. instead the homepage shows up(index.html), but now under a different url.(Normal url on homepage: localhost:8000, the new url: localhost:8000/test/details.html)
I think the problems is in the urls.py file, but i am not sure.
Hopes anyone can help.

edit:
my file folder

```
testdjango
|
|--testdjango(all the normal project files are in here)
|--test
|    |--__pycache__
|    |--migrations
|    |--templates
|    |    |--test
|    |        |--detalils.html
|    |        |--index.html
|    |        |--layout.html
|    |
|    |--__init__.py
|    |--admin.py
|    |--apps.py
|    |--models.py
|    |--tests.py
|    |--urls.py
|    |--views.py
|
|--db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code.

I'll pick the ones I've seen on first sight.

add a namespace to your `urls.py`, file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'something_meaningful'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'details/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.details, name='details')
]
```

then instead of, hardcoding url (which you've also did it wrong way), try.

```
<li class="collection-item">
    <a href="{% url 'something_meaningful: details' id=home.id %}">{{ home.title }}</a>
</li>
```

and for great god, do not use same variable name with a sequence and iterator instance.

```
{% for home in homes %}
   # ul>li block above 
{% endfor %}
```

Also you should better change `details` function like this (pk is more general).

```
def details(request, id=None):
    home = Home.objects.get(pk=id)

    context = {
    'Home': home
    }

    return render(request, 'test/details.html', context)
```

Please provide a feedback after you've done those changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have done exactly as you said, but now I get an error (in the homepage) and it says "Reverse for ' details' not found. ' details' is not a valid view function or pattern name." In my cmd everything looks find utlill I load the page, and then the same error shows up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709479/reverse-url-reverse-for-not-found-is-not-a-valid-view-function-or

Comment: I tried, but i am still getting the same error. Now the url is:     url(r'details/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.details, include('testdjango.urls', namespace='details'))